# Vuex - clearing the store at some capacity

Tags: vuex, store

I use `vuex-persist` and `localforage` as my storage plugin. I wrote a function that calculates the storage capacity (basically I access indexDB and iterate over the keys and return the size in Bytes)

I want to clear my store after I reach a certain capacity but I am having trouble figuring out **WHERE** is the **best place to call the storage calculator function.**

I have tried:

1. calculating inside the router on every page load. This becomes very slow at some point when there are several hundred mb of data in the store.
2. calculating inside a callback function in `RESTORE_MUTATION`. This is wrong because in order to access indexDB, the operation must be `async` but mutations cannot be `async`

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding point 2, mutations must be synchronous, but actions can solve this problem for you. Actions can be asynchronous and then commit the mutations.